# Configure Firehose so it writes only one record per S3 object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm using a Firehose delivery stream to write JSONs to S3. These JSONs represent calls. The stream will often receive a new version of a JSON, that bring new info about the represented call.

I would want my Firehose to write each JSON record to a separate S3 object, so not grouping them together as it seems to do by default. Each JSON would be written at an S3 key that identifies the call, so that when a new version of a JSON shows up, Firehose replaces its previous version in S3. Is this possible?

I see that I can set up the buffer size that triggers writing to S3, but can I explicitly configure my Firehose stream so it writes exactly one S3 object per record?

There's no Redshift involved.

Comment: Everything's not in the title... where are you writing to? What record are you writing? Are you attempting to perform a copy command? What have you tried so far? More is usually better when it comes to asking on SO

Comment: Fine, I'll add more, but I don't think the additional details I can provide will actually determine the answer to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with **Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose**. It is a simplified service that only has a few configuration options.

Instead, you could use **Amazon Kinesis Data Streams:**

- Send data to the stream
- Create an AWS Lambda function that will be triggered whenever data is received by the stream
- Code the Lambda function to write the data to the appropriate Amazon S3 object

See: [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon Kinesis - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html)