# Is there a way to set up AWS Kinesis Firehose to write one record per S3 object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

So I am very aware of this other thread that asks the same question: [Configure Firehose so it writes only one record per S3 object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363491/configure-firehose-so-it-writes-only-one-record-per-s3-object)

However, that was two years ago and Amazon is constantly adding/changing things.  Is this answer still valid or is there now a way to configure firehose to do this?

Comment: Firehose exists to accumulate streaming data into batches, for destinations that process batches more efficiently than individual records. As @Marcin says, a Lambda will do the job if you want one S3 object per record. But beware that doing so in a high-volume environment may make those records practically unusable: it takes non-zero time to list and read individual S3 objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly there is not. It still writes entire content of its buffer to s3. You would have to setup lambda transaction for the records and do the writing yourself using the lambda function.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I just wanted to check because a configuration option would be much faster than re-writing a cloudformation template.